# dbcontext.SaveChnages();While Inserting into db Throwing Exception DbUpdateException,Using EF5 with Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I Made my web App on Latest version of Entity Framework And mysql Connector 6.9.8.  but Due to server compatibility i had to downgrade to Entity Framwrok 5 and mysql connector 6.3.7 .

it was working fine on EF6 but when i ran this on EF5 it started throwing Exception while inserting any record.

```
lamiEntities1 lam = new lamiEntities1();
                ordered or = new ordered();
                or.PartyId = id;
                or.ItemId = itemid;
                or.Desc = txtDesc.Text;
                or.Dated = date;
                or.Qty =int.Parse( txtqty.Text);
                or.Remarks = txtremarks.Text;
                lam.ordereds.Add(or);
                lam.SaveChanges();
```

On lam.SaveChanges();i get exception **'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code"**

Note-:**I made fresh project with new modal and new web.config only Code files are old**

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace will contain more information from a SQL perspective.  My initial thoughts would be that you are violating a SQL constraint (Such as a Primary Key).

I would ensure that you are not attempting to insert a duplicate primary key into the `Ordered` table, also ensure that any foreign keys, for example `ItemId` exist in their referenced tables.

Comment: Its happeing in every table.  It was working fine on EF6.  Yes u seems right  i can see in object of entity , there is value 0 for ID column which is auto incremented.

Comment: @Akash - Try removing the ID column from your query, alternatively run a profile against MySQL and see what SQL statements are generated by Entity Framework.  Also has anything changed between your old working code and what you have now?